# Store Mongostat(Mongodb database tool command) terminal output in Excel fie

Tags: mongodb

I have been using the terminal command to save data to log file but now i need to store data in Excel file.

Command that i  have been using for log file : **mongostat --host= --port= --username= --password= --authenticationDatabase=<database_name> --humanReadable=true -n=36 1 > filename.log**

For saving the output in excel file i tried this command : **mongostat --host= --port= --username= --password= --authenticationDatabase=<database_name> --humanReadable=true -n=36 1 > filename.xls**

Excel file is also created but that is not opening with MS Excel, Error is coming : **The file format and extension of 'gift[4].xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?**

Comment: You maybe best to redirect the output to csv file  and use the import in excel later ...

Comment: @R2D2 with csv, import is not working properly.

Comment: what do you mean exactly ? Excel has very powerful import tools , you can adjust alot of details ...